# Order of operation with LTRIM/RTRIM/ISNULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, optimization, query-performance

Does the order of operation that you place your `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` matter when used in conjunction with `ISNULL`? For instance, take the following example where a user potentially enters a bunch of spaces in a field, but we trim their input to be an actual `NULL` value to avoid storing empty strings.

I am performing the `TRIM` operations outside of `ISNULL`:

```
DECLARE @Test1 varchar(16) = '    '

IF LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@Test1,''))) = ''
BEGIN
    SET @Test1 = NULL
END

SELECT @Test1
```

This appropriately returns a true `NULL` value. Now let's place `ISNULL` on the outside:

```
DECLARE @Test2 varchar(16) = '    '

IF ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Test2)),'') = ''
BEGIN
    SET @Test2 = NULL
END

SELECT @Test2
```

This also returns a `NULL` value. Both work well for the intended usage, but I'm curious if there is any difference to how the SQL query optimizer handles this?

Comment: @SQLFox I understand the difference between `NULL`, an empty string (`''`), and string literal `'NULL'` values. The purpose of my OP is to understand whether the order of operation matters or not when trimming input. If I enter space a couple of times into a web form field, I do not want to store those empty strings. I want to store a `NULL` column row. By trimming that space (`'    '`), I can evaluate an `ISNULL` expression. However, that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: If you want to replace an empty string with `NULL`, you might try `NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(@Test1)),'')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your tests are redundant. First both LTRIM and RTRIM return NULL when given NULL input:

```
declare @Test1 varchar(16) = null;

select
    lft = LTRIM(@test1),
    rgt = RTRIM(@Test1);

lft              rgt
---------------- ----------------
NULL             NULL
```

Second, standard SQL ignores trailing spaces when comparing strings:

```
select
    A =case
        when '' = '   ' then 'equal'
    end,
    B = case
        when '  ' = '     ' then 'equal'
    end;

A     B
----- -----
equal equal
```

SQL Server provides the [NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. This takes two parameters. If they differ the first will be returned. If they are equal it will return NULL. I think this will address your requirement.

```
declare @Test1 varchar(16) = '    ';

select
    first = nullif(@Test1, '');

set @Test1 = NULL;

select
    second = nullif(@Test1, '');

set @Test1 = 'some value';

select
    third = nullif(@Test1, '');

first
----------------
NULL

second
----------------
NULL

third
----------------
some value
```

You may still need the LTRIM, depending on your input validation.

Comment: Upvote simply for the fact that "standard SQL ignores trailing spaces when comparing strings".  Thank you!  Saved me a ton of time.  Although, surprised to find that out. Definitely some implicit logic that might not be desired in some instances.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server will evaluate functions inside to out. Your first example is equivalent to:

```
DECLARE @Test1 varchar(16) = '    '

SET @Test1 = ISNULL(@Test1,'')
SET @Test1 = RTRIM(@Test1)
SET @Test1 = LTRIM(@Test1)

IF @Test1 = ''
BEGIN
    SET @Test1 = NULL
END

SELECT @Test1
```

Since `ISNULL` just returns the first non-NULL value, the function just returns `@Test1`. It then goes on to trim whitespace. If you reverse the order of these it's going to act the exact same way because `ISNULL` will always evaluate to FALSE.

For your described purpose, the order is largely irrelevant. The `ISNULL` function is only needed for situations where you **don't care** about trimming whitespace, and vice versa (as `LTRIM`/`RTRIM` do nothing to NULL values).